# Resize drawable in layer-list item

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">

            <solid android:color="#000000"/>
            <size android:width="70dp" android:height="70dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_person_white_48dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />
</layer-list>
```

How can I resize the `drawable` image? Currently, it's too big for the shape.

Comment: What worked for you, I am having an issue still

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using A [ScaleDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable.html). It essentially changes the size of the child drawable using

```
android:scaleHeight="50%"
android:scaleWidth="50%"
```

Both are expressed as a percentage of the drawable's current bound.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's and old question, but this is how I resize a drawable in a layer-list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
                    <size android:width="10dp" android:height="10dp"/>
                    <padding android:bottom="30dp" android:top="30dp"
                             android:left="30dp" android:right="30dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_person_white_48dp"/>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

No need for android:height or android:width

Answer (score 0):

Drawable specifies how image to be drawn on the canvas. You tell the drawable how big it should be, and it scales or clips the underlying image to the size. You can [setBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)) on a drawable or resize the ImageView.

The following code snippet draws the drawable to a bitmap with the desired size.

```
Drawable yourDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourDrawable);
yourDrawable.setBonnds(0, 0, width, height);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
yourDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

Answer (score -3):

You could try something like this:

```
<item
    android:width="10dp"
    android:height="10dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_person_white_48dp"
    android:bottom="30dp"
    android:top="30dp"
    android:left="30dp"
    android:right="30dp"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

Comment: `android:width` and `android:height` only works for API 23 and above. How can only possible calculate the `android:top` and `android:bottom` for different devices?